# YOLOv7 does not working well after adding the Early Stopping

Tags: deep-learning, early-stopping, yolov7

[image: Training Output]

After adding the earlystopping function, the training result is weird. There are full of zeros and all the classes do not train well. Why does this happened?

[Refer (Early Stopping):](https://blog.csdn.net/qq_45374101/article/details/125984174) 
[Code:](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1YUAqp5Z2I5BAJVK6_KT2k5C3_jNX0Xjg?usp=sharing) 
[Dataset:](https://universe.roboflow.com/fyp-liv9h/rgb-smt-defects-detector-and-classifier)

I have changing some other dataset to test either is the problem on dataset but still failed. It supposed to be able to function the early stopping block and obtain satisfied training and testing results.

Answer (score 1):

There is no native `--early-stopping` ability in YOLOV7.

You can refer to this thread, https://discuss.roboflow.com/t/early-stopping-patience-in-yolov7-training/2865

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."